# Unable to create an object of type 'ApplicationDbContext'

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

This is my DbContext.

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, Guid>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {

    }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        builder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin<string>>(entity => entity.Property(m => m.LoginProvider).HasMaxLength(760));

    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseMySQL("server=localhost;database=authentication;user=root;password=root");
    }
}
```

This is my startup.cs

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {

        services.AddControllers();
        services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "JWTAuthentication", Version = "v1" });
        });
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
        {
            options.UseMySQL("Server=127.0.0.1;Database=authentication;Uid=root;Pwd=root");
        });
        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })

         .AddJwtBearer(options =>
          {
              options.SaveToken = true;
              options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
              options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
              {
                  ValidateIssuer = true,
                  ValidateAudience = true,
                  ValidAudience = Configuration["JWT:ValidAudience"],
                  ValidIssuer = Configuration["JWT:ValidIssuer"],
                  IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.Latin1.GetBytes(Configuration["JWT:Secret"]))
              };
          });
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseSwagger();
            app.UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "JWTAuthentication v1"));
        }

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
    }
}
```

> An error occurred while accessing the Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting services. Continuing without the application service provider. Error: GenericArguments[1], 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRole', on 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.UserStore`9[TUser,TRole,TContext,TKey,TUserClaim,TUserRole,TUserLogin,TUserToken,TRoleClaim]' violates the constraint of type 'TRole'.
> Unable to create an object of type 'ApplicationDbContext'. For the different patterns supported at design time, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728

Comment: Are you getting an error? If so, show us the entire message

Comment: Do you use custom user and/or role classes ? (by the way you declare twice the connection string, once in you DI container and second in the overload of the OnConfiguring method, and you seem to expose your root password)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.